# how to navigate in range of parent folder without full path?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, command-line-arguments

is there a way how to navigate to a program that is in different folder of the parent directory without using full path?

atm I have a batch here:

```
FOLDER 1\BATCHES\batch1.bat
```

which uses a program that is located in:

```
FOLDER 1\PROGRAMS\pro.exe
```

and my batch looks like this:

```
"%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Temp\FOLDER 1\PROGRAMS\pro.exe" --input "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Temp\FOLDER 1\SCRIPT\script.srpt" --output "%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Temp\FOLDER 1\FILES\myfile.x"
```

as you can see its locked to a place with `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Temp\` so in order to make my script "portable", is there something I could replace that `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Temp\`?

or putting it in another words: I would like to drop all ocurances of `%SYSTEMDRIVE%\Temp\` from my batch and replace it with something in a way that if I move my **FOLDER 1** wherever in my PC, it will run

Comment: `..\BATCHES\batch1.bat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The folder the batch resides in can be obtained with `%~dp0` (with a trailing backslash)
- The file system takes care of relative folders addressed with `..` meaning one level up.

In a `tree A: /F` like this:

```
A:.
└───Folder 1
    ├───BATCHES
    │       batch1.bat
    │
    ├───FILES
    │       myfile.x
    │
    ├───PROGRAMS
    │       pro.exe
    │
    └───SCRIPT
            script.srpt
```

This batch:

```
:: A:\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\batch1.bat
@Echo off
Echo batch1 folder is: %~dp0
Echo ======================
for %%A in ("%~dp0..\PROGRAMS\pro.exe")   Do set "_Prg=%%~fA"
for %%A in ("%~dp0..\SCRIPT\script.srpt") Do set "_Inp=%%~fA"
for %%A in ("%~dp0..\FILES\myfile.x")     Do set "_Out=%%~fA"
Set _

Echo "%_Prg%" --input "%_Inp%" --output "%_Out%"
```

will have this output:

```
A:\> "Folder 1\BATCHES\batch1.bat"
batch1 folder is: A:\Folder 1\BATCHES\
======================
_Inp=A:\Folder 1\SCRIPT\script.srpt
_Out=A:\Folder 1\FILES\myfile.x
_Prg=A:\Folder 1\PROGRAMS\pro.exe
"A:\Folder 1\PROGRAMS\pro.exe" --input "A:\Folder 1\SCRIPT\script.srpt" --output "A:\Folder 1\FILES\myfile.x"
```

Comment: if I may ask, is a `%~dp0` part with whole `for %%A in (".... ... Set_` part needed and why? I tried with just this: `"..\\PROGRAMS\pro.exe" --input "..\\SCRIPT\script.srpt" --output "..\\FILES\myfile.x"` and batch executes everything as should

Comment: The `for` is just used to resolve the expression inside the double quotes, it would also work directly, but is less clear: `A:\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\..\PROGRAMS\pro.exe` in my example.

Comment: what I meant was: yes I understand whole your answer/code... its just that both answers mention usage of `%~dp0` in a one way or another, so my question was more about: its a way of choice to use `%~dp0` or do I loose some benefit if I go without it, just and only with `"..\\PROGRAMS\pro.exe" --input "..\\SCRIPT\script.srpt" --output "..\\FILES\myfile.x"` and nothing else

Comment: Depending on context `"..\PROGRAMS\pro.exe" --input "..\SCRIPT\script.srpt" --output "..\FILES\myfile.x"` could refer to the current directory `%CD%` which is not neccessarily the same as the batch path.

Comment: I apologize if I am anoying but could you pls explain: "**...could refer to the current directory %CD% which is not neccessarily the same as the batch path.**" I reading it all over and cant understand the point

Comment: When you open a cmd window you see a prompt like `C:\Users\UserName>` all actions without expressed other path take place in this folder. If you invoke a batch with a path like `C:\Temp\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\batch1.bat` the current directory stays the same `C:\Users\UserName` so a relative path will be relative to the current folder not to the folder the batch resides in.

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider following scenario:

```
d:\bat> tree /F "d:\temp\FOLDER 1"
Folder PATH listing for volume VolName
Volume serial number is ABCD-EFGH
D:\TEMP\FOLDER 1
├───BATCHES
│       batch1.bat
│
└───PROGRAMS
        pro.exe
```

Then, use [`%~dp0` link relative to the Batch Script](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) and [`..` relative path to parent directory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#fully_qualified_vs._relative_paths) as in the following script:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
echo(
echo                                     listing "%~dp0"
dir /B /S "%~dp0"
echo                                     listing "%~dp0..\programs"
dir /B /S "%~dp0..\programs"
```

**Output**:

```
d:\bat> "d:\temp\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\batch1.bat"

                                    listing "d:\temp\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\"
d:\temp\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\batch1.bat
                                    listing "d:\temp\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\..\programs"
d:\temp\FOLDER 1\programs\pro.exe

d:\bat>
```

**Note** that `%~dp0..\PROGRAMS` **differs** from `..\PROGRAMS` generally:

- `%~dp0..\PROGRAMS` is path relative to directory where the batch resides

  - (`d:\temp\FOLDER 1\BATCHES\` in above example)
- `..\PROGRAMS`  is a path relative to current directory where the batch was started from

  - (`d:\bat\` in above example)

Comment: if I may ask, is a `%~dp0` part with whole `SETLOCAL EnableExtensions ... dir /B /S "%PathToBatch%" ... dir /B /S "%PathToBatch%..\programs"` part needed and why? I tried with just this: `"..\\PROGRAMS\pro.exe" --input "..\\SCRIPT\script.srpt" --output "..\\FILES\myfile.x"` and batch executes everything as should

Comment: My fault, sorry. Imagine `set "PathToBatch=%~dp0"` (which _was_ there in the script during debugging). Answer updated.

Comment: I meant: whats the difference between `"%~dp0..\\FILES\myfile.x"` and `"..\\FILES\myfile.x"`? And why I need `dir /B /S` ?

Comment: The difference is now explained in the updated answer.  I used `dir /B /S "%~dp0..\programs"` merely to _show result_ of using `..` in a path specification. SuperUser isn't  a free scripting service so you can't expect a foolproof solution whensoever.